# What is the difference between widget_attributes and widget_container_attributes?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

Ok, bad question since *semantically* I think I can gather the difference by the block names themselves. My real question is how can I control which attributes appear a container and an element when `widget_attributes` and `widget_containter_attributes` are required on a given element.

Consider the following:

```
<div class="ui-select foo bar baz">
    <select id="abc_hello_worldtype_name" name="abc_hello_worldtype[name]" class="thud grunt">
        ...
    </select>
</div>
```

Main things I'm going after are having to set class names on both the `div` and the `select`. This is required for both style reasons as well as behavior-related requirements.

The main thing that is confusing me is that both the original widget_attributes and widget_container_attributes both use the `attr` variable passed in. Are these not intended to be used together?

---

I found myself doing something like the following today; just making my own blocks copied from the originals and adding to the conditionals. This all seems way too complicated. I know I'm doing it wrong.

```
{% block choice_widget_collapsed %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' ui-select')|trim}) %}
    <div {{ block('ui_select_container_attributes') }}>
        <select {{ block('ui_select_widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %}>
            {% if empty_value is not none %}
                <option value=""{% if required %} disabled="disabled"{% if value is empty %} selected="selected"{% endif %}{% endif %}>{{ empty_value|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
            {% endif %}
            {% if preferred_choices|length > 0 %}
                {% set options = preferred_choices %}
                {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
                {% if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none %}
                    <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            {% set options = choices %}
            {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
        </select>
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_collapsed %}
```

Notice the `ui_*` block references on the `div` and the `select`. Those blocks look like:

```
{% block ui_select_widget_attributes %}
{% spaceless %}
    id="{{ id }}" name="{{ full_name }}"{% if read_only %} readonly="readonly"{% endif %}{% if disabled %} disabled="disabled"{% endif %}{% if required %} required="required"{% endif %}{% if max_length %} maxlength="{{ max_length }}"{% endif %}{% if pattern %} pattern="{{ pattern }}"{% endif %}
    {% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %}{% if attrname in ['placeholder', 'title'] %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue|trans({}, translation_domain) }}" {% elseif attrname == 'class' %} class="foopa {{ attrvalue|replace({'ui-select':''}) }}" {% else %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}" {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock ui_select_widget_attributes %}

{% block ui_select_container_attributes %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if id is not empty %}id="{{ id }}" {% endif %}
    {% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}" {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock ui_select_container_attributes %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a form field is rendered as *single form input* (text input, select, checkbox...), widget_attributes is used. When it is rendered as a *collection of inputs* (form, multiple checkboxes, multiple inputs, ...), widget_container_attributes is used for the container surrounding the inputs (a div, mostly). So no, they are not intended to be used at the same time.

The difference between the two blocks is that widget_attributes renders form-specific attributes ("value", "name"...) while widget_container_attributes renders only generic HTML attributes.

If you want to add additional markup beyond the possibilities of the "attr" option, your best bet is to copy the corresponding block from the form theme (e.g. "choice_widget_collapsed"), paste it into your template, rename the block to match your element's ID with a leading underscore ("_") and a "widget" suffix (e.g. if your element's ID is "form_my_element", the block would be called "_form_my_element_widget") and modify the markup in your template.

```
{% block body %}
...
{{ form(form) }}
...
{% endblock %}

{% block _form_my_element_widget %}
... modified version of the "choice_widget_collapsed" markup ...
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is the `_..._widget` block a convention or is it recognized internally by Symfony?

Comment: It is recognized internally. Usually the "choice_widget" block would be rendered here (which internally renders "choice_widget_collapsed") but in this way you can override the block for only one specific form field.

Comment: Don't forget that your template will need `{% form_theme form _self %}` for this to work.